# How do you input multiple SELECT outputs into a FROM clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do something similar to the following in MySQL, but every permutation I try gives me errors.

```
SELECT five,six FROM (SELECT 5 AS five),(SELECT 6 AS six);
```

I was under the impression that SELECT's output table's, so that I could use SELECT whereever I could insert a table.

Can someone explain the subtleties of the structre of MySQL that prevents this statement from working as well as providing me a solution that does?

I know that it's got to be simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: This works fine in MySQL what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.0.37, but my employer may have customized things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding aliases:

`SELECT five, six FROM (SELECT 5 AS five) AS a, ( SELECT 6 AS six) AS b`

Comment: Every derived table needs an alias. (the "AS a", "AS b" parts in the query)
The error message for your original query was: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Because you can use the selects as a field as well. `select (select 5 as five) as five`. Without the aliases, MySQL wouldn't be able to tell where the sub-select is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but this works

```
select five,six from (select 5 as five, 6 as six) as t;
```

It's obvious useless cause it's the same of

```
select 5 as five, 6 as six
```

but I hope that it helps you.

Comment: I was just simplifying the example.  I actually have 2 massive SELECT statements, so it'd be much more difficult to merge them.